# How can I display all guessed numbers in this lottery function?

Tags: javascript

I've created some simple lottery function in JS. All works fine.

The only issue I'm facing is how to display all numbers which have been guessed?

I have 6 independent spaces where numbers must be provided and my goal is to display the rolled number from random space, it must be just provided in one of the 6 spaces. That works for me, but only 1 number displays.

I'm looking for solution how to display all the guessed numbers?

```js
function losowanie1() {
  var wybor = 6;
  var dostepne = 6;
  r = new Array(dostepne)

  var xd0 = document.getElementById("pole1").value
  var xd1 = document.getElementById("pole2").value
  var xd2 = document.getElementById("pole3").value
  var xd3 = document.getElementById("pole4").value
  var xd4 = document.getElementById("pole5").value
  var xd5 = document.getElementById("pole6").value

  y = new Array(6)
  y[0] = xd0
  y[1] = xd1
  y[2] = xd2
  y[3] = xd3
  y[4] = xd4
  y[5] = xd5

  z = new Array(6)

  for (var i = 0; i <= dostepne - 1; i++) {
    r[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * (49 - 1)) + 1);
    if ((y[i] == r[0]) || (y[i] == r[1]) || (y[i] == r[2]) || (y[i] == r[3]) || (y[i] == r[4])) {
      document.getElementById("zatw").innerHTML = y[i]
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("wysw").innerHTML = r;
}
```

```html
<div id="wysw"></div>
<div id="dupa">
  <input type="text" id="pole1" /><input type="text" id="pole2" /><input type="text" id="pole3" /><input type="text" id="pole4" /><input type="text" id="pole5" /><input type="text" id="pole6" />
  <br></br>
  <input type="reset" id="tak" value="zatwierdz" onclick="losowanie1();" />
  <br></br>
  <div id="zatw"></div>
```

Comment: `pole*` are input elements?

Comment: So you want to randomly pick one of the 6 input elements is that what your asking?

Comment: The numbers are overwriting each other. Can you insert your HTML?

Comment: Yes, pole are input elements which are binded to the button and after clicking the button the script checks if provided numbers are the same with rolled numbers.

Comment: document.getElementById("zatw").innerHTML = y[i]  it only displayes one rolled number. If I hit two numbers for instance, still only one is displayed.

Comment: Nope, still don't understand what your asking

Comment: Ahaa I get it. You insert 6 numbers and the script checks (after creating random ones) if you guessed some.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yup

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand what you want now, (thanks to @RokoC.Buljan) but I don't understand what your missing?

Comment: @Liam Only one number is displaying, even if I hit more.I want to display 2 numbers if I hit 2, 3 numbers if hit 3 etc.

Comment: Display where? You only ever write to one place `document.getElementById("zatw").innerHTML`. You need multiple places to write to. It'd help a lot of you added your HTML

Comment: @Liam I have edited my post and added whole html

Comment: @ledinos1 ....in the code above, how do you prevent your script from generating multiple repeated numbers?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan haven't fixed it yet

Comment: @ledinos1 in the code above how do you prevent the user from entering an already used number?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Haven't done it neither. Once I will figure the displaying thing, I will focus on the cosmetic things.

Comment: FYI: `<br></br>` is invalid. use only `<br>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS lotto simulator - how to display the established amount of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033100/js-lotto-simulator-how-to-display-the-established-amount-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

What the below still misses is to make sure the user don't repeats numbers in the inputs.
I won't do that since I would neither use inputs for that purpose, but rather predefined checkboxes (yes, 38 checkboxes) and make sure , on submit, exactly 6 are **checked**.

Anyways, hope this might be helpful:

```js
function lottoGenerate(min, max) {
  // Shuffle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/383904
  const a = Array.from({length: max}, (_, v) => v + 1);
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a.slice(0, min);
}

function play() {
  const guessed_nums = [];
  const lotto_nums = lottoGenerate(6, 38); // Generate 6 random unique lotto numbers 
  const player_nums = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.num')).map(el => {
    const n = parseInt(el.value, 10);
    const isGuessed = lotto_nums.includes(n);
    if (isGuessed) {
      guessed_nums.push(n); // Insert the guessed number!
      el.style.background = 'lightgreen';
    } else {
      el.style.background = 'red'
    }
    return n
  });

  document.getElementById('gen').textContent = lotto_nums.join(', ');
  document.getElementById('player').textContent = player_nums.join(', ');
  document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = `
    You guessed ${guessed_nums.length} numbers!<br>
    The numbers are: ${guessed_nums.join(', ')}
  `;
}

document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', play);
```

```html
<input class="num" type="number" min=1 max=38 value="1">
<input class="num" type="number" min=1 max=38 value="2"><br>
<input class="num" type="number" min=1 max=38 value="3">
<input class="num" type="number" min=1 max=38 value="4"><br>
<input class="num" type="number" min=1 max=38 value="5">
<input class="num" type="number" min=1 max=38 value="26"><br>
<button id="play">PLAY LOTTO 6/38</button>
<div>Numbers: <span id="gen"></span></div>
<div>User played: <span id="player"></span></div>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: I have fixed the script myself but I have another thing I cannot figure out. How to modify the script to make it displaying numbers only when some conditions are made for instance display numbers only when two of them or more were guessed.