# JS lotto simulator - how to display the established amount of numbers

Tags: javascript

I've created simple lotto simulator and I want to set it to display numbers only when particular conditions are made. Let's say, to display numbers at least two or more must be covered (chosen and rolled) I'm the beginner so apologizes for any obvious mistakes, I'm still learning.

```js
var attempt = 0;

function losowanie1() {
  var available = 6;
  var guessed = new Array();

  r = new Array(available);

  var xd0 = document.getElementById("pole1").value
  var xd1 = document.getElementById("pole2").value
  var xd2 = document.getElementById("pole3").value
  var xd3 = document.getElementById("pole4").value
  var xd4 = document.getElementById("pole5").value
  var xd5 = document.getElementById("pole6").value

  y = new Array(6)
  y[0] = xd0
  y[1] = xd1
  y[2] = xd2
  y[3] = xd3
  y[4] = xd4
  y[5] = xd5

  z = new Array(6)



  for (var i = 0; i <= available - 1; i++) {
    r[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * (49 - 1)) + 1);
    if ((y[i] == r[0]) || (y[i] == r[1]) || (y[i] == r[2]) || (y[i] == r[3]) || (y[i] == r[4]) || (y[i] == r[5])) {
      guessed.push(y[i]);
    }



  }

  atempt++
  document.getElementById("wysw").innerHTML = r;
  document.getElementById("zatw").innerHTML = guessed;
  document.getElementById("zatw2").innerHTML = attempt;
}
```

```css
#wysw {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}


}
#zatw {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
#dupa {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: brown;
  text-align: center
}
#tak {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 850px;
}
#zatw2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Totolotek</h1>
    <div id="blokada">
      <br>
      <div id="wysw"></div>
      <div id="dupa">
        <input type="text" id="pole1" /><input type="text" id="pole2" /><input type="text" id="pole3" /><input type="text" id="pole4" /><input type="text" id="pole5" /><input type="text" id="pole6" />
        <input type="reset" id="tak" value="zatwierdz" onclick="losowanie1();" />
        <div id="zatw"></div>
        <div id="zatw2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: So, I've started you off on a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552); please [edit] your question, click "edit this snippet" and add the corresponding HTML. Then we can run the code and help you easier.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Done. I had to multiply my answer as I could not edit the post due to "more code than details"

Comment: It looks like you have `atempt++` instead of `attempt++` as I posted in my answer. This is pretty obvious from the console error: `message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: atempt is not defined",`

Comment: Instead of duplicating the existing text, perhaps you can expand the text you have by telling us what the code should do that it's not &c. See [ask] for more hints on what to put into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2er8w9j/) - I just sort of guessed at what you're doing.

You had a typo: `atempt++`.

It seems to work after fixing that.

```
var attempt = 0;

function losowanie1() {
var available = 6;
var guessed = new Array();

r = new Array(available);

var xd0 = document.getElementById("pole1").value
var xd1 = document.getElementById("pole2").value
var xd2 = document.getElementById("pole3").value
var xd3 = document.getElementById("pole4").value
var xd4 = document.getElementById("pole5").value
var xd5 = document.getElementById("pole6").value

y = new Array(6)
y[0] = xd0
y[1] = xd1
y[2] = xd2
y[3] = xd3
y[4] = xd4
y[5] = xd5

z = new Array(6)



for (var i = 0; i <= available - 1; i++) {
  r[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * (49 - 1)) + 1);
  if ((y[i] == r[0]) || (y[i] == r[1]) || (y[i] == r[2]) || (y[i] == r[3]) || (y[i] == r[4]) || (y[i] == r[5])) {
    guessed.push(y[i]);
  }



}

attempt++
document.getElementById("wysw").innerHTML = r;
document.getElementById("zatw").innerHTML = guessed;
document.getElementById("zatw2").innerHTML = attempt;
}
```